# Kafka in error mode natively

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a problem with my Kafka. It is always in error mode. I unistalled and installed no change. When I restart no change. These are the logs.

I get the logs when I run,
`kafka-server-start /usr/local/etc/kafka/server.properties`

```js
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,107] INFO KafkaConfig values:
 advertised.host.name = null
 advertised.listeners = null
 advertised.port = null
 authorizer.class.name =
 auto.create.topics.enable = true
 auto.leader.rebalance.enable = true
 background.threads = 10
 broker.id = 0
 broker.id.generation.enable = true
 broker.rack = null
 compression.type = producer
 connections.max.idle.ms = 600000
 controlled.shutdown.enable = true
 controlled.shutdown.max.retries = 3
 controlled.shutdown.retry.backoff.ms = 5000
 controller.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
 create.topic.policy.class.name = null
 default.replication.factor = 1
 delete.topic.enable = false
 fetch.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
 group.max.session.timeout.ms = 300000
 group.min.session.timeout.ms = 6000
 host.name =
 inter.broker.listener.name = null
 inter.broker.protocol.version = 0.10.2-IV0
 leader.imbalance.check.interval.seconds = 300
 leader.imbalance.per.broker.percentage = 10
 listener.security.protocol.map = SSL:SSL,SASL_PLAINTEXT:SASL_PLAINTEXT,TRACE:TRACE,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
 listeners = null
 log.cleaner.backoff.ms = 15000
 log.cleaner.dedupe.buffer.size = 134217728
 log.cleaner.delete.retention.ms = 86400000
 log.cleaner.enable = true
 log.cleaner.io.buffer.load.factor = 0.9
 log.cleaner.io.buffer.size = 524288
 log.cleaner.io.max.bytes.per.second = 1.7976931348623157E308
 log.cleaner.min.cleanable.ratio = 0.5
 log.cleaner.min.compaction.lag.ms = 0
 log.cleaner.threads = 1
 log.cleanup.policy = [delete]
 log.dir = /tmp/kafka-logs
 log.dirs = /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs
 log.flush.interval.messages = 9223372036854775807
 log.flush.interval.ms = null
 log.flush.offset.checkpoint.interval.ms = 60000
 log.flush.scheduler.interval.ms = 9223372036854775807
 log.index.interval.bytes = 4096
 log.index.size.max.bytes = 10485760
 log.message.format.version = 0.10.2-IV0
 log.message.timestamp.difference.max.ms = 9223372036854775807
 log.message.timestamp.type = CreateTime
 log.preallocate = false
 log.retention.bytes = -1
 log.retention.check.interval.ms = 300000
 log.retention.hours = 168
 log.retention.minutes = null
 log.retention.ms = null
 log.roll.hours = 168
 log.roll.jitter.hours = 0
 log.roll.jitter.ms = null
 log.roll.ms = null
 log.segment.bytes = 1073741824
 log.segment.delete.delay.ms = 60000
 max.connections.per.ip = 2147483647
 max.connections.per.ip.overrides =
 message.max.bytes = 1000012
 metric.reporters = []
 metrics.num.samples = 2
 metrics.recording.level = INFO
 metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
 min.insync.replicas = 1
 num.io.threads = 8
 num.network.threads = 3
 num.partitions = 1
 num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir = 1
 num.replica.fetchers = 1
 offset.metadata.max.bytes = 4096
 offsets.commit.required.acks = -1
 offsets.commit.timeout.ms = 5000
 offsets.load.buffer.size = 5242880
 offsets.retention.check.interval.ms = 600000
 offsets.retention.minutes = 1440
 offsets.topic.compression.codec = 0
 offsets.topic.num.partitions = 50
 offsets.topic.replication.factor = 3
 offsets.topic.segment.bytes = 104857600
 port = 9092
 principal.builder.class = class org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.DefaultPrincipalBuilder
 producer.purgatory.purge.interval.requests = 1000
 queued.max.requests = 500
 quota.consumer.default = 9223372036854775807
 quota.producer.default = 9223372036854775807
 quota.window.num = 11
 quota.window.size.seconds = 1
 replica.fetch.backoff.ms = 1000
 replica.fetch.max.bytes = 1048576
 replica.fetch.min.bytes = 1
 replica.fetch.response.max.bytes = 10485760
 replica.fetch.wait.max.ms = 500
 replica.high.watermark.checkpoint.interval.ms = 5000
 replica.lag.time.max.ms = 10000
 replica.socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
 replica.socket.timeout.ms = 30000
 replication.quota.window.num = 11
 replication.quota.window.size.seconds = 1
 request.timeout.ms = 30000
 reserved.broker.max.id = 1000
 sasl.enabled.mechanisms = [GSSAPI]
 sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
 sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
 sasl.kerberos.principal.to.local.rules = [DEFAULT]
 sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
 sasl.mechanism.inter.broker.protocol = GSSAPI
 security.inter.broker.protocol = PLAINTEXT
 socket.receive.buffer.bytes = 102400
 socket.request.max.bytes = 104857600
 socket.send.buffer.bytes = 102400
 ssl.cipher.suites = null
 ssl.client.auth = none
 ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
 ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
 ssl.key.password = null
 ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
 ssl.keystore.location = null
 ssl.keystore.password = null
 ssl.keystore.type = JKS
 ssl.protocol = TLS
 ssl.provider = null
 ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
 ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
 ssl.truststore.location = null
 ssl.truststore.password = null
 ssl.truststore.type = JKS
 unclean.leader.election.enable = true
 zookeeper.connect = localhost:2181
 zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms = 6000
 zookeeper.session.timeout.ms = 6000
 zookeeper.set.acl = false
 zookeeper.sync.time.ms = 2000
 (kafka.server.KafkaConfig)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,209] INFO starting (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,213] INFO Connecting to zookeeper on localhost:2181 (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,268] INFO Starting ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,288] INFO Client environment:zookeeper.version=3.4.9-1757313, built on 08/23/2016 06:50 GMT (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,288] INFO Client environment:host.name=192.168.10.51 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,289] INFO Client environment:java.version=1.8.0_131 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,290] INFO Client environment:java.vendor=Oracle Corporation (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,290] INFO Client environment:java.home=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/Contents/Home/jre (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,291] INFO Client environment:java.class.path=:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/aopalliance-repackaged-2.5.0-b05.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/argparse4j-0.7.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-api-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-file-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-json-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-runtime-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/connect-transforms-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/guava-18.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-api-2.5.0-b05.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-locator-2.5.0-b05.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/hk2-utils-2.5.0-b05.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-core-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-databind-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-base-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.8.5.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javassist-3.20.0-GA.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.inject-1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.inject-2.5.0-b05.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.servlet-api-3.1.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-client-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-common-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-container-servlet-core-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-guava-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-media-jaxb-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jersey-server-2.24.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-continuation-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-http-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-io-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-security-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-server-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlet-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-servlets-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jetty-util-9.2.15.v20160210.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/jopt-simple-5.0.3.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-clients-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-log4j-appender-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-streams-examples-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka-tools-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0-sources.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0-test-sources.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/kafka_2.11-0.10.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/log4j-1.2.17.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/metrics-core-2.2.0.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/reflections-0.9.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/rocksdbjni-5.0.1.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-library-2.11.8.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.21.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/snappy-java-1.1.2.6.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zkclient-0.10.jar:/usr/local/Cellar/kafka/0.10.2.0/libexec/bin/../libs/zookeeper-3.4.9.jar (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,300] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/Users/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:. (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,301] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/var/folders/rd/v5rrgfr929q8gvxl8y0hqvdm0000gn/T/ (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2017-06-16 12:13:45,301] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```js
FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-0/00000000000000000000.index (Permission denied)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
 at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
 at kafka.log.AbstractIndex.<init>(AbstractIndex.scala:50)
 at kafka.log.OffsetIndex.<init>(OffsetIndex.scala:52)
 at kafka.log.LogSegment.<init>(LogSegment.scala:72)
 at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegments$4.apply(Log.scala:210)
 at kafka.log.Log$$anonfun$loadSegments$4.apply(Log.scala:188)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
 at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
 at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
 at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
 at kafka.log.Log.loadSegments(Log.scala:188)
 at kafka.log.Log.<init>(Log.scala:116)
 at kafka.log.LogManager$$anonfun$loadLogs$2$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(LogManager.scala:157)
 at kafka.utils.CoreUtils$$anon$1.run(CoreUtils.scala:57)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-06-16 12:13:46,489] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

What can be the issue? I'm on OSX.

Comment: can you paste the entire log ?

Comment: Could you please provide the other bits of the stack trace? it would help in understanding the issue.

Comment: Updated. SO was limiting. The logs exceed the number of characters required.

Comment: Could you run your broker with log.dir only and remove the log.dirs configuration? Another pointer to clean the older logs from log.dirs.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-0/00000000000000000000.index`? And what user is running the kafka server? Because it looks like a simple file permissions problem to me.

Comment: Yes, permission issue makes sense. I've run as sudo, it hasn't exited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-0/00000000000000000000.index (Permission denied)
```

The above line suggests that your kafka process does not have enough permission to write into the following path,

**/usr/local/var/lib/kafka-logs**

Find the owner and group of the above directory and start the kafka service with either the same user as the owner or change the owner and group of the directory accordingly.

Most probably, you might need to run the kafka service as **sudo** user.

Comment: This is very helpful. I've started Kafka as sudo and the server is not breaking.